# Pandas: Read CSV file with separate Year & Month columns, merge them and set as index column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-conversion

I have a csv file that contains a column `'Year'` (type: int64) e.g. 1958, and a column `'Month'` (type: int64) e.g. 7 for July.

I would like to convert these two columns into one (format should be 'YYYY-MM') and set it as the index column. 
So far I tried this:

```
    data_two = pd.read_csv('data/archive.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=[['Year','Month']], date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y%M"), index_col="date_time")
```

Comment: Do you want output as datetime or as string?

Comment: You are aware that you can keep them as separate columns yet use as the index, so they get sorted correctly: `df.set_index('Year','Month')` ?

Answer (score 1):

First if need `Datetimeindex` need set `index_col` by `Year_Month`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Year,Month,Col
1958,7,2
1991,6,4"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 parse_dates=[['Year','Month']],  
                 index_col="Year_Month")

print (df)
            Col
Year_Month     
1958-07-01    2
1991-06-01    4

print (df.index)

DatetimeIndex(['1958-07-01', '1991-06-01'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', 
              name='Year_Month', freq=None)
```

EDIT:

If need string index (`YYYY-MM`) then first create `MultiIndex` with both columns and then `join` them by `list comprehension`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Year,Month,Col
1958,7,2
1991,6,4"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 index_col=['Year','Month'])

print (df)
            Col
Year Month     
1958 7        2
1991 6        4

df.index = ['{}-{:02d}'.format(i,j) for i,j in df.index]
print (df)
         Col
1958-07    2
1991-06    4
```

Answer (score 1):

As the format you are requesting (%Y-%M) is not a datetime representation you could simply skip parsing dates and do this:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u'''\
Year,Month,Col
1958,7,2
1991,6,4'''

# Read sample dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=',')

# Set index
df = (df.set_index(df.Year.astype(str)+"-"+df.Month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
      .drop(['Month','Year'],axis=1))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Col
1958-07    2
1991-06    4
```

---

The alternative is to do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 parse_dates=[['Year','Month']],  
                 index_col="Year_Month")

df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I used the alternative you showed me. Works perfectly !!!

Comment: (I tagged datetime, not the OP. They are a string representation of a (partial) datetime)